# How to get the location of the UICollectionViewCell in self.view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used the code below to get the location of the cell when touched.
However, when the `UICollectionView.bounds.size.width` > 320, or > 640, the "origin.x" returned often > 320, for example, 657, 469. Cause there are some images inside cells. So when I touched the cell on the second page. The value X returned may be 368.0 or other values.

I just need to get the value X in the current view.(320 * 480).

`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// attach long press gesture to collectionView
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr 
   = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    return;
}
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
if (indexPath == nil){
    NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");            
} else {
    // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
    UICollectionViewCell* cell =
    [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // do stuff with the cell
}
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737183/getting-the-screen-location-of-a-cell-from-a-uicollectionview

Comment: Wow! It works well for my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your collection view may have multiple pages horizontally. Assuming these pages are frame-width, you could do this:

```
int xVal = (int)p.x % (int)self.view.frame.size.width;
```

Keep in mind that you will lose decimal precision.

Comment: In this case, decimal precision probably isn't that important.