# How to get position of selected item of collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my project there is a grid of users. I made grid using collection view. When user taps on cell I need position or frame of selected cell. I have used touch event of view but it's not working in the case of collection view.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
    print(location)
}
```

also this method works when you touch rest of UIView expect collectionView items.

Comment: Cristik, This method is same for objective-c that's why I tagged. Maybe syntax is different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following method to get the cell attributes

```
func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
```

and then get the frame using frame property

```
let attributes = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at:indexPath)
let frame = attributes.frame
```

PS- you might have to convert the frame of the cell from UICollectionView to your controller's view to get its exact position.

```
func convert(_ rect: CGRect, 
    from view: UIView?) -> CGRect
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to use:

```
let cPoint = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath).center
```

But after that you need to convert the point to your View's Coordinate system like so:

```
let centerPoint = collectionView.convert(center ?? CGPoint.zero, to: collectionView.superview)
```

Here is a full code snippet:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let attributes = self.collectionView?.layoutAttributesForItem(at:indexPath)
    let cPoint = attributes?.center

    /*
    this is nice. but when we scroll passed the visible items -
    we see that the point is given in the collectionView's coordinates.

    we need to convert the point to the collectionView.superview coordinate system
    */
    //solution:
    let centerPoint = collectionView.convert(cPoint, to: collectionView.superview)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to achieve what you want in `UICollectionView` delegate that you can use it to find out which cell has clicked:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   YourCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   let frame = cell.layer.frame
   // here you can do what you want with frame
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **indexPathsForSelectedItems** returns an array of index paths (since there might be several items selected) so you need to use:

```
let indexPaths : NSArray = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
let indexPath : NSIndexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
```

(You should probably test to see whether several items are selected, and handle accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all you for your good response and i found solution for same.

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
let tap = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
let convertedTap = cell.convert(tap, to: self.view)
```

When you will print `convertedTap` you will get exact position of collection item cell with respect to view.

Answer (score 0):

its very easy . 
In swift the position is called  as indexpath.
when you select a particular cell in collectionview its position is identified by index path

//initialise did select function in your view controller

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

}
```

//note
you can get indexpath in your "cellforItematIndexpath" function